# Assassin's Creed II keep on crashing

Tags: steam, assassins-creed-2, ubisoft-connect

I recently purchased this game, Assassin's Creed II Deluxe Edition, mainly because it looked interesting and it was on sale. So I bought it and installed it. When I lauched the game, it gave me the product activation code, then after that, it downloaded and installed Uplay for me automatically. Then, the Uplay prompted me to create an account, so I did. Right after that, it kept on crashing whenever I attempt to start the game. What is wrong here?

Computer Specs:
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200U CPU @ 160 GHz
4.00GB RAM
x64 processor
Windows 8.1 K OS

Comment: It would appear that your game is not working. Why yes, I do work in IT, how did you know?

Comment: Umm actually I asked on Steam Forums and almost everybody is having the same problem... and nobody knows how to fix it so I just asked here, to see if anyone knows how.

Comment: Could you give more detail about your computer specs? A screenshot right before or during the crash? Whether or not it was on Steam or UPlay?

Comment: Sure, I can get the specs, but not the screenshot... my screenshot kinda fails as well whenever I launch steam, just noticed this yesterday.

Comment: @KimMinseo you forgot to mention your most important gaming asset, the GPU

Comment: I had some trouble with ACIII recently and it was fixed by going to the uplay website and downloading uplay from there and installing it. Seems the Steam version was messed up. Might be worth a try.

Comment: @Elgert I think my graphics card is Intel(R) HD... I am not so sure.

Comment: @user85756 It still is the same... still crashes whenever I lauch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this and do it for your games executable 
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-run-older-programs-under-windows-8.html
and select windows 7 and then press OK and play

Comment: I can't find the compartibility mode options...

Comment: It should be there when you go to the properties of the executable

Comment: Oh wait, I got it, finally managed to lauch it... thx :)